# Lungs permeability

Tags: respiration, breathing, organs, lungs

My question is:

$O_2$ and $CO_2$ pass to (in & out) the bloodstream due to difference in partial pressure and its permeability to those gases (I suppose that's why no $N_2$ passes). So, to what other molecules do lungs are permeable and what molecules can and can't pass to the bloodstream from the lungs?

Thank you.

Comment: VTC as too broad. All manner of things pass into the blood through the lungs. Anesthetic gasses like halotane, aerosolized drugs (vaping TC), CO, and too many others to list.

Comment: Nitrogen do indeed pass to the bloodstream from the lungs. That is what divers experience when breathing compressed air. It causes decompression sickness and nitrogen narcosis.

Comment: For the N2, we do not absorbe a lot of that, do we? I mean, where can I find the proportions of absorption (most of air is N2 but we don't absorb that proportion of N2 from air although N2 partial pressure is higher than O2). Do we absorbe all gases that go through lungs? Must say I'm really noob in these themes, so thank you for your answers.

Comment: When the blood is in equilibrium with the ambient atmosphere, the net transport of N2 to and from the blood is equal to zero. However, this dosen´t mean that no nitrogen crosses the blood-lung membrane, only that the amount entering equals  the amount leaving.

Comment: SOME ANSWERS HERE https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSAggw7-B8xkNYtd6-y2i70YFwopQ%3A1571218905884&ei=2eWmXa6_NZLRxgPz2oWYDw&q=MOLECULES+THAT+CAN+BE+ABSORBED+BY+LUNGS&oq=MOLECULES+THAT+CAN+BE+ABSORBED+BY+LUNGS&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30l2.11408.16251..16381...0.4..0.116.3507.32j7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i273j0j0i67j0i10i67j0i20i263j0i22i30j0i13i30.GEIFqmfe_Vk&ved=0ahUKEwjuj__FvqDlAhWSqHEKHXNtAfMQ4dUDCAs&uact=5

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, it's now clearer to me.